# How to get the X value from a known Y value for a line chart in C#?

Tags: c#, charts, axis, series

I'm creating a graph in C# which plots an X value (distance) against Y (time).
The graph has two lines: A line to compare to (we can call IdealDistance) and a line generated from an external input (RealDistance).[image: Graph of time(Y) vs distance(X)]

I was wanting to compare the RealDistance X value to the IdealDistance X value at the time it is added but can't work out how to return the IdealDistance X value at known times (or IdealDistance Y values).

The IdealDistance line is formed by a number of datapoints spaced out every second, the desired check is done every 100ms so can't simply use the IdealDistance set of datapoints unfortunately.

- How can I get the X axis value of one of my series at a given Y axis value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take two data points (a and b) you can use the equation of a line to get Y for any X point (or X for any Y point) between them:

```
public static int GetX(int y, Point a, Point b)
{
    var m = CalculateSlope(a, b);

    // Horizontal line (x-values are always the same)
    if (m == 0.0)
        return a.X;

    var c = a.Y - a.X * m;

    return Convert.ToInt32((y - c) / m);
}

public static int GetY(int x, Point a, Point b)
{
    var m = CalculateSlope(a, b);

    // Vertical line (y-values are always the same)
    if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(m))
        return a.Y;

    var c = a.Y - a.X * m;

    return Convert.ToInt32(m * x + c);
 }


public static double CalculateSlope(Point a, Point b)
{
    if (b.Y == a.Y)
        return double.PositiveInfinity;

    if (b.X == a.X)
        return 0.0;

    return (Convert.ToDouble(b.Y) - Convert.ToDouble(a.Y)) / (Convert.ToDouble(b.X) - Convert.ToDouble(a.X));
}
```

Comment: this is a good way to do it for lines. However was there a way to account for if there was a spline type with soft corners?

Comment: I think you're talking about calculating equation of irregular curve? The maths would get a bit complex if so.

Comment: Yes that would be required to do it this way. It is alright I will stick with the line graph for now. Would be easier to implement the pixel method to determine position for the curved graph. I will mark your answer as correct if you change it to correctly implement for GetX rather than GetY, or I can update with how I implemented the code which is based off yours but mildly different.

Comment: @Luke I added the GetX method.